# Haystack-Django TemplateDoesNotExist at /search/ Error

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am trying to integrate haystack into my Django App

Here is the DIR structure :

```
vaibhav@ubuntu:~/temp/hayStackDemo/demoApp/templates/search$
pwd
/home/vaibhav/temp/hayStackDemo/demoApp/templates/search
vaibhav@ubuntu:~/temp/hayStackDemo/demoApp/templates/search$ ls
indexes  search.html
```

And i am getting this error : `TemplateDoesNotExist at /search/`

And some Django DEBUG Info :

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/search/search.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/search/search.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/templates/search/search.html (File does not exist)
/home/vaibhav/temp/hayStackDemo/demoApp/templates/search/search.html (File does not exist)
```

I did not understand why i am getting this error... where i have done wrong...

settings.py :

```
# Django settings for hayStackDemo project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/home/vaibhav/temp/hayStackDemo/sqlite.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '=7*wk@+p^*)zghrt)+021wh%uj&amp;si+f^8yw%j6+2yo%1)w^vy7'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hayStackDemo.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hayStackDemo.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                 '/home/vaibhav/temp/hayStackDemo/demoApp/templates'        
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'haystack',
    'demoApp'
)


HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # url(r'^$', 'HayStackDemo.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^HayStackDemo/', include('HayStackDemo.foo.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'))
)
```

Comment: I know this type of question has been asked earlier but they didn't resolved mu issue..can someone please help me..

Comment: This is weird. Just a shot in the dark - could it be a permissioning issue ?

Comment: Tried that by giving whole project DIR `chmod 777` but nothing happened

Comment: Could you post your settingsfile please?

Comment: Posted have a look...

Comment: It looks ok - could you post your urls.py also?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having just the same problem and I don't have even a hint of how to solve it.

Comment: @vaibhavjain are you using any kind of extends in your search.html??

Answer (score 3):

It's possible the problem is on file "search.html". Change this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

by this:

```
{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}
```

See the solution on bottom of this page: https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1205

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error is cause by failure to include your app in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. Check to make sure your app is installed